# JSON.parse() how to prevent alphabet sorting of keys

Tags: json

I have JSON string that I retrieve from server:

```
"{ \"id\": 1, \"name\": \"Bill\", \"fields\": [\"a\", \"b\"] }"
```

When I do `JSON.parse()` then it sorts keys in alphabetical order:

```
{ fields: ["a", "b"], id: 1, name: "Bill" }
```

How can I prevent this sorting?

Comment: Looking at this from a different angle... Why does it *matter* what order the object properties are in?  How are you observing that order and what problem does it cause?

Comment: @David I just want to show them on UI in order - base properties (number, string, bool) - first and then complex properties (like nested objects or arrays).

Comment: What you have is just data with no guaranteed order.  If you need to display it in a specific order then you'd need to put that ordering logic in the display logic.  (Conceptually this is no different than querying a database table with or without an `ORDER BY` clause, though in this case your sorting logic may be more complex.)

Comment: If you really need some help you will have to show us the code you are using for UI.

Answer (score 1):

Official specification (json.org) states:

> "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs."

The order or properties should not matter, your application should have same results regardless. If you design your application around this order, it is a mistake.

Comment: I just want to show them on UI in order - base properties (number, string, bool) - first and then complex properties (like nested objects or arrays).

Comment: Then sort the list of the keys based on the order you desire and do processing based on that.

Exp. ```Object.keys(obj).sort( (a,b) => complexity(obj[a])-complexity(obj[b]) )```, where complexity is the function that asseses the complexity of the property.